# Assigning static ip to gcp vm using node js script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-compute-api

I am trying to assign static ip to gcp VM using a node js script,

so far I have been able to create static ip globally but I am not able to understand weird documentation google gloud platform has

```
    'use strict';
    const compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
    const { GlobalAddressesClient } = require('@google-cloud/compute').v1;

    const project = "test-1234";

    const addressResource = {
        name: "test-static-3"
    }


    // Instantiates a client
    const computeClient = new GlobalAddressesClient({ keyFile: './keys.json' });

    // create ip addredd
    async function callInsert() {
        // Construct request
        const request = {
            addressResource,
            project,
        };

        // Run request
        const response = await computeClient.insert(request);
        console.log(response);
    }
    callInsert();
```

with above script I can create a static ip globally...

Comment: This link shows how to assign a static external IP address to a VM: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#rest_2 The node.js API: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/latest/compute/v1.instancesclient#_google_cloud_compute_v1_InstancesClient_updateAccessConfig_member_1_